# Selecting Different rows from multiple gridviews

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am working on an asp.net project and I have to put two different gridviews on the webpage independent of each other.

In the scenario, I want the user to select single row from both the views for which I have used select button in both.

Selecting any row from any of the gridview first time works fine, but when the user selects a row from the OTHER gridview, the webpage reloads and forgets the selected row from the previous gridview. How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: In which Event are you binding the gridviews?

Comment: in page_load event, using linq

Comment: obviously no :D, I think I have got the answer :P

Comment: @KiranHegde Thank You so very much, this and a little bit more coding, solved my issue. Thank You for your time.